# Show that $| A |\leq | A^S|$ for any $A$ and any $S\neq \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proposition: If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets and $f : A → B$ is a 1-1 function, then
|A| ≤ |B|.

Given the function $f : A → A^S$ I need to prove that it is injective.

I define the function as follows: for each $a\in A$ we have $f(a)=a^s$

Let $a,b\in A$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ I must prove that $a=b$

If $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a^s=b^s$ which implies that $a=b$.

Is my demo correct?

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood the notation $A^S$: it is the set of functions from $S$ to $A$, so you have to define your function $f$ in such a way that each $f(a)$ is a function from $S$ to $A$. Your notation $a^s$ really doesn’t have any meaning here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you recommend me how to define the function?

Comment: HINT: Make each $f(a)$ a constant function.

Comment: means that for each $a\in A$ define $f (a) = k$ where $k$ is constant?

Comment: More accurately for each $a\in A$ you want to define a constant functionn $f(a):S\to A$; if it’s constant with value $k$, it’s the function $f(a)$ from $S$ to $A$ such that $(f(a))(s)=k$ for each $s\in S$. What constant $k$ in $A$ is the most natural one to use? Remember, you want $f$ to be injective, so you need a different constant value for each of the functions $f(a)$.

Comment: For your first proposition... shouldn’t it be the case that if $f: |A| \mapsto |B|$ is bijective, then $|A| = |B|$? (Rather than a weak inequality)

Answer (score 1):

Your demo world be correct if you defined $a^S$ as the function

$\psi_{a}:S\to\{a\}$

such that

$\psi_{a}(s)=a\quad$ for all $\;s\in S$